# Big non-repeat background, need preloader for loading parts of one

Tags: css, background, background-image

I have [background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp3KJ.jpg), picture size is 6 MB and I can't write `background: url(...)`.

This long page consists of 6 parts and I decide to divide the background to 6 pictures and I want each block's background to load after each other and show a preloader in each block before the background loads.

```
<div class="page" id="page_1">
   <div class="preloader"></div>
   <div class="page-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page_2">
   <div class="preloader"></div>
   <div class="page-content"></div>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page_3">
   <div class="preloader"></div>
   <div class="page-content"></div>
</div>
.......
```

Comment: My God. Six *megabytes*? There is no way to do what you're trying to do, nor should there be. That is orders of magnitude too large for use on a website. The solution is to redesign, not to try to find a way to stream your background image in segments. Remove your footer from the image and allow the image to repeat. It's a terrible, awful practice to include text in an image anyways.

Comment: @meagar Even for a sprite (I just learnt what that means recently `:)`), that _is_ big...

Comment: I understand that i cant do it easy, but it is designer requirement, i am no designer, i'm developer

Comment: If the designer requires something impossible, it's your *job* as the developer to tell them as much.

Comment: @ozerich: then take the designer out back and drop a stack of harddrives and routers on them. Forcing users to download a 6meg image JUST to be a background is outright ludicrous. Especially if they're a mobile user. Your site will be a graveyard, littered with the corpses of cell browsers you've bankrupted.

Comment: The image is only 670kb, not 6mb...

Comment: Note that I'm using "only" lightly. 670k is still a bit on the large side.

Comment: oh..i have saved as PNG(6.7M), yes JPG is 670k, very very good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @meager's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676022/big-non-repeat-background-need-preloader-for-loading-parts-of-one#comment17106350_12676022), you will be better off splitting the the part with the ship in it, the footer and the repeating background. I already did your homework for this one.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YatharthROCK/MRUxf/) to see how I tested it.

## HTML Code

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="top-image">
    </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

## CSS Code

For the top part:

```
#top-image {
    background: url('top.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /*to counteract the default value*/

    width: 100%; /*this may get screwed up otherwise*/
    height: 850px; /*allowing a bit more height to remain safe*/
}
```

For the middle repeating part:

```
body {
    background: url('middle.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-y; /*want this one to repeat*/
    background-position: 0px 835.5px; /*so it fits perfectly with the overlayed image*/
}
```

For the bottom footer:

> Figure it out yourself! Nah, kidding. Just use the same principle I used above for the top part.

## Images

The top ship part:
[image: top]

The middle repeating part:
[image: middle]

The footer:
[image: bottom]

Comment: thanks for answer, but i cant repeat this picture because colors at black part and white shadows is different!

Comment: @Ozerich Give me a second. I'm working on it.

Comment: @Ozerich There, it's finished. Can you offer a bounty, please? Doing this really wrung my neck and I have an exam tomorrow (I'm 13, so I have exams — middle school sucks in that regard).

Comment: @Ozerich Can you at the very least, get me a few more hits on [ma blog](http://YatharthROCK.blogspot.com/)? And maybe [circle me](https://plus.google.com/115093555862694271963/about) or [follow me](https://twitter.com/YatharthROCK)?